# Error: three.projector has been moved to /examples/js/renderers/projector.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, windows-10

I had this error: three.projector has been moved to /examples/js/renderers/projector.js
[image]

and I don't use projector.js in my project.

I'm using **windows 10 Pro or Enterprise OS Build 14393.321** with **Chrome browser Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit)**, I get the same issue when I open http://threejs.org Examples and Editor. Or any project using threejs library.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: So you're saying that if you open the [ThreeJS Editor](https://threejs.org/editor/), you see that error?

Comment: Yes, or any site using threejs library